# Using Cloudfront as a HAProxy backend server with https

Tags: https, amazon-cloudfront, haproxy

I have a CloudFront resource sitting in front of my S3 bucket. It's accessible at —

```
https://<id>.cloudfront.net
```

but if I hit —

```
<id>.cloudfront.net:443
```

I get a 400 Bad Request. I want to point to CloudFront in my HAProxy configuration, but I can't use the `443` port because of the above-mentioned issue. Nor can I use the `https` URL protocol in the server statement.

```
backend my_cloudfront_app
    http-response set-header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000
    server my_server <id>.cloudfront.net:443
```

How can I hit HTTPS cloudfront from this server block in HAProxy?

Answer (score 1):

I assume You will need to add some infos to the request headers for the cloudfront backend.

This example works with HAProxy 2.0

```
backend my_cloudfront_app
    http-response set-header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000

    # Add backend header for cloudfront backend request
    http-request set-header Host <id>.cloudfront.net

    # maybe you will need to add a S3 prefix to the request path
    # http-request set-path <CLOUDFRONT_S3_Prefix>%[path] 

    server my_server <id>.cloudfront.net:443 sni str(<id>.cloudfront.net) ssl verify none
```